# Mail shoot from server while receiving error from volley in android

Tags: php, android, networking, android-volley, connection-timeout

I am sending some data from my app to the server using volley library. When the network connection is too slow then I got volley timeout error and received no response from the server but server shoots an email. I have asked for the solution but nothing works. Please provide me some solution

Comment: Probably something in php script after sending email is delaying the response back to the phone.

Comment: What you need is Multithreading on server . Send Mail in saperate thread ..